# Setting a title of a button from shuffled array - Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

That's my code

```
    func shuffle() {
    let footballClubsInPoland = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: self.footballClubsInPoland)
    option1.setTitle((footballClubsInPoland[0] as AnyObject).name, for: .normal)
    option2.setTitle((footballClubsInPoland[1] as AnyObject).name, for: .normal)
    print(footballClubsInPoland[0])
    print(footballClubsInPoland[1])
}
```

My problem is that I can see in a console the objects, that were shuffled, but titles of my buttons are not loading in a simulator. What should I do?

Comment: What's the type of `footballClubsInPoland` array ?

Comment: Code lokks like this:

var footballClubsInPoland: [footballClubs] = []

and typical object there looks like this

    var ruchChorzow: footballClubs = footballClubs(name: "Ruch Chorzów", trophies: 29)

Comment: Why are you casting it to AnyObject ?

Comment: Did you try setTitle with some string (for instance replace `(footballClubsInPoland[0] as AnyObject` to "Hello world", is it displayed in the UI then ?)

Comment: that was a proposition from XCode to solve this problem

Comment: Yes, I did and then it is displayed.

Comment: I think I understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `(footballClubsInPoland[0] as AnyObject` you are casting the elements to AnyObject, and when calling `.name` you aren't actually referring to the `name` property of `footballClubs`.

So you should rather do:

```
func shuffle() {
    let footballClubsInPoland = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: self.footballClubsInPoland) as! [footballClubs]
    option1.setTitle(footballClubsInPoland[0].name, for: .normal)
    option2.setTitle(footballClubsInPoland[1].name, for: .normal)
    print(footballClubsInPoland[0])
    print(footballClubsInPoland[1])
```

Comment: Trevor - thank You for your patience. Everything works now :)